# How do you write text beyond the boundaries of a textbox without it adding a new line?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox with it's multiline property set to true, and dragged it out.
As it stands, whenever I type and the next word is going to be beyond the boundaries of the textbox, it'll create a new line instead. I want to be able to keep typing without it adding a  new line.

Like in Notepad, when you're going to write beyond the boundaries of the box, it'll let you keep typing and won't start at a new line untill you press enter. Instead, you can just use the scrollbar to scroll horizontally between your text. How do I do that with the textbox?

Comment: Just set its `ScrollBars` property to `ScrollBars.Both`.

Comment: @Adriano I already did but there's no use in doing it if everytime you're going to write beyond the boundaries of the textbox it starts you at a new line instead. As a result, there's nothing to scroll to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning off the word wrap feature:

```
textBox1.WordWrap = false;
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! I swear I looked through all the properties before I asked this question. Guess I didn't really understand what the description meant.